# Best approach to storing image pixels in bottom-up order in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d, raster

I have an array of bytes representing an image in Windows BMP format and I would like my library to present it to the Java application as a `BufferedImage`, *without* copying the pixel data.

The main problem is that all implementations of `Raster` in the JDK store image pixels in top-down, left-to-right order whereas BMP pixel data is stored bottom-up, left-to-right.  If this is not compensated for, the resulting image will be flipped vertically.

The most obvious "solution" is to set the `SampleModel`'s `scanlineStride` property to a negative value and change the band offsets (or the `DataBuffer`'s array offset) to point to the top-left pixel, i.e. the first pixel of the last line in the array.  Unfortunately this does not work because all of the `SampleModel` constructors throw an exception if given a negative `scanlineStride` argument.

I am currently working around it by forcing the `scanlineStride` field to a negative value using reflection, but I would like to do it in a cleaner and more portable way if possible.
e.g. is there another way to fool the `Raster` or `SampleModel` into arranging the pixels in bottom-up order but without breaking encapsulation?  Or is there a library somewhere that will wrap the `Raster` and `SampleModel`, presenting the pixel rows in reverse order?

I would prefer to avoid the following approaches:

- Copying the whole image (for performance reasons.  The code must process hundreds of large (>= 1Mpixels) images per second and although the whole image must be available to the application, it will normally access only a tiny (but hard-to-predict) portion of the image.)
- Modifying the `DataBuffer` to perform coordinate transformation (this actually works but is another "dirty" solution because the buffer should not need to know about the scanline/pixel layout.)
- Re-implementing the `Raster` and/or `SampleModel` interfaces from scratch (because of the way compatibility checking is implemented (at least in the Sun JDK), requiring specific subclasses of `SampleModel` so a generic `BottomUpSampleModel` wrapper class would not work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I can implement this using only one new class, which I named `BottomUpComponentSampleModel`.  It extends `ComponentSampleModel` and negates the value of the `scanlineStride` field (which, luckily, is `protected` rather than `private`) after calling the superclass constructor.  All of the pixel address calculations work fine, although the validation in `Raster.createWritableRaster` does not (it can fail to detect if you give it an array that is too small), but that is not a serious problem.

This is not necessary with `MultiPixelPackedSampleModel` or `SinglePixelPackedSampleModel`, as they do accept a negative `scanlineStride`.  They do not have band offsets, but this can be worked around by setting an offset on the `DataBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

what about having the application (or access layer) do the translation and fliping work on it's copy when accessing the tiny (but hard-to-predict) portion of the image?

Comment: Possible, but the application still needs to work with non-flipped images.  I could add an "`isFlipped`" argument but that seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

even better, it sounds like the application doesn't need to actually display the image?
Why bother with wanting to flip it in the first place so it would look correct on screen? Just write the logic to work on the version you have?
No need to have a BufferedImage that way either, work directly on the array.

Comment: It needs to work with a variety of pixel formats (8, 16, 24 or 32bpp.) This is already implemented by the various subclasses of `ColorModel` and `SampleModel` and I would prefer not to re-implement pixel format conversion.  Also the client code already operates on instances of `BufferedImage` from other sources (e.g. decoded PNG files.)